# How do I change the sorting layer in Unity programmatically?

Tags: sorting, unity-game-engine, layer

I am making a 2D game. I am confused because there are two types of Layers. Layers and "Sorting Layers". It seems that only the "Sorting Layers" matter.

I have many objects on each layer and I want to set the "Sorting Layer" programmatically. I've tried

```
item.layer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("IslandLayer");
```

but that only sets the Layer and not the "Sorting Layer". Is there a way to set the "Sorting Layer" programmatically?

Comment: The sorting layer is in the [sprite renderer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-SpriteRenderer.html).

Comment: layer and sorting layer is different category. for your case you can just set sortingLayer name

Comment: GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sortingLayer = "sortingLayerName"
or if you use Image then you need to change it using Canvas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you changed was the [`GameObject.layer`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject-layer.html) which is the "other" [Layer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html), not the [SortingLayer](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SortingLayer.html).

---

The sorting layer is rather changed in the according `Renderer` component e.g. via the [`Renderer.sortingLayerID`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-sortingLayerID.html) using [`SortingLayer.NameToID`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SortingLayer.NameToID.html)

```c#
item.GetComponent<Renderer>().sortingLayerID = SortingLayer.NameToID("NameOfTheSortingLayer");
```

Comment: Doesn't that need to be `GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>()`?

Comment: @trojanfoe Nope .. as you can see in the link it is a property of the general `Renderer` base class. If you look at the API of [`SpriteRenderer`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SpriteRenderer.html) you can see it is listed under "Inherited Properties" ;)